# C#: Open password protected PDF with Docotic.Pdf library

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, bitmiracle, docotic.pdf

I have a code which extracts text from PDF documents, As such some PDFs are password protected, I need a way to Identify if a PDF is password protected

I am using.`BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf` library.

> Purpose:- If I find the PDF as password protected then I will show a dialog prompt to user to enter password and then open PDF using that password.

**Edit 1:** Solution posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that [`IsPasswordProtected()`](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/help/pdfdocument.ispasswordprotected.aspx) method provided in library which returns a `Boolean` value if current specified file is password protected or not.

Solution:

```
BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfcontent=null;

public static string GetText(string filename)
{
    if (PdfDocument.IsPasswordProtected(filename))
    {
        //method to show dialog for password
        pass=getPassword()
        using (pdfcontent = new PdfDocument(filename, pass))
        {
            return pdf.GetTextWithFormatting();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (pdfcontent = new PdfDocument(filename))
        {                    
            return pdf.GetTextWithFormatting();                
        }
    }
}
```